# Nuxt Auth Module - How to create Success Redirect

Tags: vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js, auth0

I'm trying to a page in my nuxt app, where the user is on a dynamic route. On this route he has the possibility to log in and should then be redirected to exactly the same route. For the authentification I want to use the auth0 strategy.

I thought the following line would work:

```
this.$auth.loginWith('auth0')                 
  .then(() => {                               
    this.$router.push("/the-same-route-im-already-on");  
  })
```

But apperently I'm only redirected to my home route "/loggedin". And changing the home redirect in my nuxt.config to false, redirects me to my callback-route "/login"

Right now my nuxt.config.js looks like this:

```
auth: {  
    auth0: {
     ...
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/',
      logout: '/',
      callback: '/login',
      home: '/loggedin',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the default behavior of rewriteRedirect in nuxt Auth Module, should redirect you to the original guarded route.

[rewriteRedirect](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/options.html#rewriteredirects)

If this is not working maybe you could redirect the user to login route manually passing a query like this

```
this.$router.push({ path: '/login', redirect: 'actualRoute' });
```

And then check in your login page if redirect is setted and then after login you call $router passing the value of redirect.

I don't know if this will help you, so let me know.